# XignCode Bypasser installer for Blade & Soul

Tags: beginner, file-system, batch

As the title says, this batch script installs the XignCode Bypasser.

Xigncode is a software bundled with games to analise running programs and prevent cheating.  (Sometimes, it prevents the game to load at all on the newest Windows releases.)

For this, a bypasser was created that disables this check, allowing players to run the game (if they couldn't), mod the game (One Click Tool, for example) and (if you want) cheat.

Copying the files manually is a boring task that can lead to mistakes (copying from the wrong location, deleting the Bypasser by mistake, ....).

For that, I've made the following batch script that does all the copying and extraction:

```
@echo off

REM set the title - https://stackoverflow.com/a/39329524
title XignCode Bypasser installer
color 07

REM config
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set CALLPATH=%~dp0
set FILESPATH=!CALLPATH!
set WIN_BITS=64
set REGKEY="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\NCWest\BnS"

REM needs administrator rights - https://stackoverflow.com/a/21295806
REM we run fsutil to check the error code. 0 = admin
fsutil dirty query %SystemDrive% >nul 2>&1
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    call :kill 1 "You need to execute as administrator"
)

REM detect the bitness and fixes values - https://superuser.com/a/268384
echo %PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE% | find /i "x86" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    set WIN_BITS=32
    set REGKEY="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\NCWest\BnS"
)

REM checks if the game is running - https://stackoverflow.com/a/1329790
tasklist /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq Blade & Soul" 2>nul | find /I /N "Client.exe" >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    call :kill 1 "Close the game before installing the Xigncode Bypasser"
)

set WIDTH=80
for /f "tokens=1*" %%a in ('mode con') do (
    IF "%%a" EQU "Columns:" (
        set "WIDTH=%%b"
    )
)

REM this key is required - https://stackoverflow.com/a/445323
REM we check if it exists before trying to run the code
REG QUERY !REGKEY! >nul 2>&1
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    REM call :kill 1 "Registry key !REGKEY! not found"
    call :colorecho "Registry key !REGKEY! not found" red black
    call :pause "Press any key to select the game installation directory"
    call :getfolder "Select game installation folder"

    IF [!getfolder!] EQU [] (
        call :kill 1 "Folder selection canceled"
    )
    set "AppPath=!getfolder!\"
) ELSE (
    REM fetches the data in the registry
    for /f "tokens=2*" %%a in ('REG QUERY !REGKEY! /v BaseDir') do set "AppPath=%%~b\"

    IF NOT EXIST "!AppPath!*" (
        call :colorecho "!AppPath! does not exist or is empty" red black
        call :pause "Press any key to select the game installation directory"
        call :getfolder "Select game installation folder"

        IF [!getfolder!] EQU [] (
            call :kill 1 "Folder selection canceled"
        )
        set "AppPath=!getfolder!\"
    )
)

:startpatch
REM ready to replace everything

cls
call :colorecho "This will install the XignCode Bypasser" black gray
call :line
echo Game installation: !AppPath!
echo Files in: !FILESPATH!
echo Detected !WIN_BITS! bit Windows installation
call :line

:choice
echo What to do next?
choice /c:qigeb /n /m "[Q]uit | [I]nstall | [G]ame folder | [B]ypasser folder | [E]xtract ZIP"

IF ERRORLEVEL 5 (
    REM [B]ypasser folder

    call :getfolder "Select XignCode Bypasser folder"

    IF [!getfolder!] EQU [] (
        call :colorecho "Folder selection canceled" darkyellow black
        goto choice
    ) ELSE (
        IF NOT EXIST "!getfolder!\*" (
            call :colorecho "Folder is empty" red black
            goto choice
        ) ELSE (
            set "FILESPATH=!getfolder!\"
            goto startpatch
        )
    )

) ELSE (
    IF ERRORLEVEL 4 (
        REM [E]xtract ZIP
        call :zipfile "!CALLPATH!"
        IF ERRORLEVEL 255 (
            call :colorecho "No suitable extraction program found" darkred black
            goto choice
        )
        IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
            goto choice
        )
        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
            call :colorecho "File selection canceled" darkyellow black
            goto choice
        )
        IF ERRORLEVEL 0 (
            set FILESPATH=!zipfile!
            goto startpatch
        )
    ) ELSE (
        IF ERRORLEVEL 3 (
            REM [G]ame folder
            call :getfolder "Select game installation folder"

            IF [!getfolder!] EQU [] (
                call :colorecho "Folder selection canceled" darkyellow black
                goto choice
            ) ELSE (
                IF NOT EXIST "!getfolder!\*" (
                    call :colorecho "Folder is empty" red black
                    goto choice
                ) ELSE (
                    set "AppPath=!getfolder!\"
                    goto startpatch
                )
            )
        ) ELSE (
            IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
                REM [I]nstall
                call :line

                REM call the patching function
                for %%b in (32,64) do (
                    IF %%b LEQ !WIN_BITS! (
                        call :patch %%b
                        IF ERRORLEVEL 1 (
                            call :colorecho "Installation for %%b bits was skipped" darkyellow black
                        )
                    )
                )

                call :line
                call :colorecho "The XignCode Bypasser was successfully installed!" darkgreen black
            ) ELSE (
                REM [Q]uit
                call :line
                call :colorecho "You decided to quit the installer" darkyellow black
            )
        )
    )
)

call :kill 0 "More in http://bnsbuddy.com/ and https://www.reddit.com/r/BladeAndSoulMods/"

REM =====================
REM FUNCTION DECLARATION!
REM =====================

:line
REM draws a line width the width of the console
call :repeat _ !WIDTH!
echo %repeat%
goto :eof

:repeat
REM https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#Batch_File
REM repeats a char n times
REM %1 = char, %2 = times
REM exit: 1 = times missing
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

IF [%2] EQU [] (
    REM closest thing to a return
    REM explained below
    endlocal & set "repeat="
    exit /b 1
)
set char=%1
for /l %%i in (1,1,%2) do set res=!res!%char%

REM since %res% is expanded on compilation time
REM     it will have the correct value before endlocal
REM     has any effect, working as a "return"
endlocal & set "repeat=%res%"
goto :eof


:getfolder
REM fetches a folder path
REM %1 = title
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set txt='Please choose a folder.'
IF NOT [%1] EQU [] (
    set txt=%1
    set txt=!txt:"=!
)

REM executes the folder dialog - https://stackoverflow.com/a/15885133
set "cmd="(new-object -COM 'Shell.Application').BrowseForFolder(0,'%txt%',0,0).self.path""
for /f "usebackq delims=" %%I in (`powershell -NoProfile -Noninteractive -NoLogo %cmd%`) do set "folder=%%I"

endlocal & set "getfolder=%folder%"
goto :eof

:colorecho
REM prints a message with specific colors
REM %1 = message, %2 = text color, %3 = background color, %4 = extra arguments (like -NoNewline)
REM https://www.petri.com/change-powershell-console-font-and-background-colors
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

powershell -NoProfile -Noninteractive -NoLogo Write-Host %1 -ForegroundColor %2 -BackgroundColor %3 %4

goto :eof


:pause
REM handles the pausing
REM %1 = message
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set a=%1
echo !a:"=!

pause >nul

goto :eof

:kill
REM creates the exit messages
REM %1 = exit code, %2 = message
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

IF NOT [%2] EQU [] (
    IF %1 EQU 0 (
        set a=%2
        echo !a:"=!
    ) ELSE (
        call :colorecho %2 red black
    )
)

call :pause "Press any key to exit."
exit %1

goto :eof

:patch
REM function to handle the patching
REM %1 = bitness
REM exit: 1 = skipped
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

set bits=%1
set folder=!FILESPATH!!bits!\
set dll=bsengine_Shipping
set target=!AppPath!\bin

IF NOT !bits! EQU 32 (
    REM 64bit paths need treatment -.-
    set dll=!dll!!bits!
    set target=!target!!bits!
)

REM make sure the folder with the contents exist
IF NOT EXIST "!folder!*" (
    call :kill 1 "Folder !bits! does not exist or is empty"
)

REM it exists, confirm the remaining
IF NOT EXIST "!folder!XignCode\*" (
    call :kill 1 "Folder !bits!\XignCode does not exist or is empty"
)
IF NOT EXIST "!folder!!dll!.dll" (
    call :kill 1 "File !bits!\!dll!.dll does not exist"
)

echo Folder !bits! found, preparing to copy files ...

REM verifying if the bypasser was already installed may save work
REM step 1 - verify if the dll exists
IF EXIST "!target!\XignCode\!dll!.dll" (
    REM step 2 - compare if they are the same. if they are ...
    fc /b "!folder!!dll!.dll" "!target!\XignCode\!dll!.dll" >nul
    IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        REM step 3 - check if the x3.xem file is the same (original one is different)
        fc /b "!folder!XignCode\x3.xem" "!target!\XignCode\x3.xem" >nul
        IF %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
            REM step 4 - faily certain it's already installed, ask user input
            call :colorecho "The bypasser was already installed for !bits! bits." darkyellow black
            choice /c:yn /n /m "Install anyway? [Y] Yes | [N] No"
            IF ERRORLEVEL 2 (
                exit /b 1
            )
        )
    )
)

REM hacky way to echo without a new line
echo | set /P ="Copying files "
call :colorecho . darkgreen black -NoNewline

REM begin copying the directory
xcopy "!folder!XignCode" "!target!\XignCode\" /i /s /q /y >nul 2>&1
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    call :colorecho . darkred black
    call :kill 1 "Error (%ERRORLEVEL%) while copying the folder !bits!\XignCode"
)

call :colorecho . darkgreen black -NoNewline

REM copy the dll file
copy "!folder!!dll!.dll" "!target!\XignCode\!dll!.dll" /b /y >nul 2>&1
IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
    call :colorecho . darkred black
    call :kill 1 "Error (%ERRORLEVEL%) while copying the file !bits!\!dll!.dll"
)

call :colorecho . darkgreen black

goto :eof

:zipfile
REM opens a file dialog that allows to choose the zip file
REM     also "returns" the path where the folder is when done
REM %1 = optional target for extraction
REM exit: 0 = extracted, 1 = skipped, 2 = failed
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

REM https://stackoverflow.com/a/50115044
REM fix for dialog not showing: https://stackoverflow.com/q/216710
set cmd=powershell -NoProfile -Noninteractive -NoLogo -command "&{[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.windows.forms')|Out-Null; $F = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog; $F.ShowHelp = $true; $F.filter = 'ZIP Archive (*.zip)| *.zip'; $F.ShowDialog()|Out-Null; $F.FileName}"

for /f "delims=" %%i in ('!cmd!') do (
    set filedrive=%%~di
    set filepath=%%~pi
    set filename=%%~ni
    set fileext=%%~xi
)

IF "!filedrive!!filepath!!filename!!fileext!" EQU "" (
    endlocal & exit /b 1
)

set "folder=!filedrive!!filepath!"
set "file=!filename!!fileext!"

set target=%~dp1
IF "!target!" EQU "" (
    SET target=%TEMP%\
)

set code=255

REM UNTESTED!!! CAN'T TEST THIS!
REM https://stackoverflow.com/q/1825585
set psv=powershell -NoProfile -Noninteractive -NoLogo -command "$psversiontable.PSVersion.Major"
for /f "tokens=1" %%i in ('!psv!') do (
    IF %%i GEQ 5 (
        echo Using Powershell version %%i to extact
        REM https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.archive/expand-archive?view=powershell-6
        powershell -NoProfile -Noninteractive -NoLogo Expand-Archive "!folder!!file!" "!target!!filename!" >nul
        IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
            call :colorecho "Failed to extract: error %ERRORLEVEL%" red black
            set code=2
        ) ELSE (
            endlocal & set "zipfile=%target%%filename%\"
            exit /b 0
        )
    )
)

REM https://stackoverflow.com/q/14122732
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" (
    echo Using 7-Zip to extact
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" x "!folder!!file!" -bd -y -o"!target!!filename!\" >nul
    IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        call :colorecho "Failed to extract: error %ERRORLEVEL%" red black
        set code=2
    ) ELSE (
        endlocal & set "zipfile=%target%%filename%\"
        exit /b 0
    )
)

REM https://stackoverflow.com/a/19337595
IF EXIST "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\winrar.exe" (
    echo Using WinRAR to extact
    "%ProgramFiles%\WinRAR\winrar.exe" x -ibck "!folder!!file!" *.* "!target!!filename!\" >nul
    IF NOT %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
        call :colorecho "Failed to extract: error %ERRORLEVEL%" red black
        set code=2
    ) ELSE (
        endlocal & set "zipfile=%target%%filename%\"
        exit /b 0
    )
)

exit /b !code!
```

This script has many functionalities:

- Automatically fetches the game installation path from the registry
- Automatically detects the Windows "bitness" (to decide if it patches the 64-bit folder or not)
- Allows to change the game installation path for the running script
- Extracts the files and automatically assumes the path where they were extracted to
- Verifies if it was already installed, allowing to skip or install anyway

Knowing it is a rather large script, I've tried to split it into multiple functions, to make it easier to understand, read and maintain in the future.

You can see the complete instruction list on https://github.com/ismael-miguel/xcb-installer

As far as I know and tested, this is working as it should.  All it's functionalities function as intended and there seem to be no obvious errors.

Regarding readability, error handling and readability, is there anything else I can improve?

---

**Disclaimer:**

Seeing that this action of bypassing XignCode may be against the Terms and Conditions of the game, I've asked about it on [Are we allowed to post questions that allow you to do something that may be against the Terms and Conditions of another software?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8800/are-we-allowed-to-post-questions-that-allow-you-to-do-something-that-may-be-agai) (to which 13 upvoted the only answer, 1 downvoted).

This script does not allow you to get the files in any way, shape or form: it only does all the extracting and copying.  If you want the files, you have to get them by yourself.  I do not want to make it any easier to get the needed files.

Batch is a language I'm not familiar with, requiring me to learn a lot from all the websites and links available in comments.